# Decorating a static class C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, decorator, factory-pattern, static-classes

I've got a design question.

I've got a static class used in some old code that calls a static method to run some operation. If a certain condition is met, I want to call another method right after it.

I wanted to use the decorator pattern but I can't exactly return an instance of the static class if the condition is not met.

This is what's happening now.

```
var result = StaticClass.DoSomething(some parameters);
```

What I want is to write to a database right after that DoSomething is called if another variable is true and I didn't want to just pile on to the old code with conditionals so I'd rather delegate that to some other class. This is what I really want to do.

```
var result = StaticClassFactory(condition).DoSomething(some parameters);

Class1
void DoSomething(parameters) {
StaticClass.DoSomething()
}

Class2
void DoSomething(parameters) {
StaticClass.DoSomething();
DoSomethignElse();
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is use an interface to represent the "doer":

```
public interface IDoer
{
    void DoSomething(object parameters);
}
```

Then create the two classes:

```
public class DefaultDoer : IDoer
{
    public void DoSomething(object parameters) 
    {
        StaticClass.DoSomething(object parameters);
    }
}

public class AugmentedDoer : IDoer
{
    public void DoSomething(object parameters) 
    {
        StaticClass.DoSomething(object parameters);
        DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

Then use a factory to return an instance that implements IDoer based on the condition:

```
public class DoerFactory
{
    public IDoer GetDoer(object someCondition)
    {
        //Determine which instance to create and return it here
    }
}
```

I used placeholders of type `object` for some things as no more information is available.

Comment: I like this but for decent encapsulation, it might be nicer to to make an abstract Doer class with a virtual DoStuff() method which calls a non-virtual DoSomething() method.  Then you can inherit it cleanly for DefaultDoer and inherit with an overrride on DoStuff() on AugmentedDoer.  This means you only write the DoSomething() code once.

Stick with the Factory though!

Comment: Precisely, @RichBryant. There are other ways of doing it but I stuck to what the OP is looking for.